# Fluctuation in accuracy with varying size of training data

Tags: machine-learning

I am currently working on a project. I have come across an issue that the accuracy of the classifier is fluctuating with the size of training data set.
For ex:

```
Training data set% |Accuracy %
10%                | 50
20%                | 60
30%                | 55
40%                | 65
50%                | 80
60%                | 70
....               | ...
```

My doubt is that I have chosen weak features..like those features are very diverse and there is no dominating feature. Does anyone have any other solution for this?

Comment: I'm guessing you ran each experiment only once (per training set size). If so, can you report average accuracies across 5 runs per training size?

Comment: No, I ran each experiment for 31 times. It maybe because of my dataset is very limited. So, i am getting this kind of result.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of "fluctuations" means that your model has high variance, which is probably caused by the size of the dataset. If you want to not observe fluctuations your training set size (using 10%!) should be large enough to be representable of your problem. If your problem is at least a bit complex, and is not a simple binary classification in 2D, this means that you should probably gather ~10,000 samples (so 10% is 1000). Otherwise - there is nothing weird about this. You can try to gather this accuracy in bootstrapped manner (sample with replacement to create training sets) and repeat hundreads of times - this should stabilize results a bit without sacrificing statistical meaning.